# I want to make a video background, and I need the video to change size relative the screen resolution, without zooming the video in

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, html5-video

I have recently been having a problem with a video background. The video background itself is working fine, it was rendered for me by a friend in 4k and I was able to input it into my background via this code:

Html=

```
<video autoplay loop muted poster="css/videobackground/poster.png" id="video-bg">
    <source src="css/videobackground/GLitch4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Css=

```
#video-bg {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%     !important;
    height: auto    !important; 
    z-index: -1;
    background: transparent url(videobackground/poster.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

It's supposed to be really simple, but after testing it on a a heap of different screen sizes throughout my school, at home and at friends houses, each with very different resolutions. I found that on the thinner screens, using this exact code made a white strip appear along the bottom of the screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/99nqo.jpg
I fixed this by changing the width and height to:

```
width: auto     !important;
height: 100%    !important;
```

But this means that on very widescreen computers, it creates a white strip along the left side of the screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0T2g.png
I have also tried making both the width and height set to 100%, but on wide screens, this makes two white strips appear either side of the video (or the background image) and on very thin/tall screens, white strips appear on the bottom and top of the screen (or the background image). The one other thing I have tried is making both width and height set to auto/cover (both do the same thing):

```
width: auto     !important;
height: auto    !important;
```

Which works, it makes the video full screen and not create any white strip on any screen resolution, **but**, it makes the video appear very zoomed in and I can no longer get that very clean, 4k look to the video. Instead it looks pixelated and extremely zoomed in.

I am wondering if anyone can help me set parameters to the video so it's full screen on any resolution **without** making it zoomed in. This may mean that the video is stretched/squished on some screens, but I would rather have the stretched/squished effect to the video than white strips down the sides and bottom/top or the zoomed in affect. If anyone can help, please do. (I have external javascript files, so if this problem requires javascript or JQuery, that's fine.)

Comment: *"after testing it on a a heap of different screen sizes throughout my school, at home and at friends houses"* - you can always use Chrome Developer tools to simulate different screen sizes in a faster manner... But yeah... Testing on actual devices is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can using the `z-index` and the height will be `auto`

Try to resize is at JSfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/uwwpmode/